# Do shin injuries heal slower than similar injuries on other parts of the body?

Tags: coloration-discoloration, blood-circulation, self-healing-repairing, bruising-bruise

Do common injuries, such as scrapes and bruises, heal up slower on your shins? It seems as though there would be less blood flow through shins than, say, the upper arm (which is more "meaty").

Comment: Please remove all personal details of your injuries and just ask the question.

Comment: I thought all these details were pertinent: our age, the bruising, the scrape, the current state of each injury, and whether there was still any pain. Which ones are irrelevant?

Comment: Personal medical advice is off topic here. That's why Graham asked you to remove personal details. As he said, just ask the question. Details aren't needed.

Comment: @Nour Please read the comments above. Adding a photo would make the question squarely off topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is commonly known by plastic surgeons etc that the close association of skin and bone in the shin area leads to poor healing.  Anatomical studies suggest that this is caused by the comparative lack of deep perforating vessels.

https://www.jprasurg.com/article/0007-1226(81)90061-8/pdf